# OAS Quantlib of Callable Bond

Tags: python, quantlib

I am attempting to determine the OAS of of a callable bond in QuantLib. However, my results are always negative!?

I am wondering if there is some issue in the call schedule, as the bond yield returned from pricing the bond under the Hull White model seems to be reasonable.

Consider the following bond contract:

```
import QuantLib as ql
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


bf = ql.BondFunctions
qd = ql.DateParser.parseFormatted

# Conventions
accrual_convention = ql.Unadjusted
Rule = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
endofMonth = False
firstDate = None

# OAS
compounding = ql.Compounded
frequency = ql.Annual

calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

a = 0.1
sigma = 0.1
grid_points = 100
face_amount = 100
mkt_price = 78

contract = {
    'IssueDate': ql.Date(30,6,2016),
    'MaturityDate': ql.Date(15,6,2023),
    'SettlementDays': 2,
    'FirstCouponDate': ql.Date(15,12,2016),
    'NextToLastCouponDate': ql.Date(15,12,2022),
    'RealValue': 0.0675,
    'FirstCallDate': ql.Date(15,6,2019),
    'OptionalityEndDate': ql.Date(15,6,2023),
    'OperatingCountry': 'US',
    'StrikeDate': [ql.Date(15,6,2019), ql.Date(15,6,2020), ql.Date(15,6,2021)],
    'OptionalityType': ['Call', 'Call', 'Call'],
    'NoticeDays': [30, 30, 30],
    'StrikePrice': [103.375, 101.688, 100.0]}

# Here is the zero curve:

times= np.array(['0 MO', '1 MO', '2 MO', '3 MO', '6 MO', '1 YR', '2 YR', '3 YR',
       '5 YR', '7 YR', '10 YR', '20 YR', '30 YR'], dtype=object)

dates = [ql.Date(9,2,2017), ql.Date(9,3,2017), ql. Date(9,4,2017),
         ql.Date(9,5,2017),ql.Date(9,8,2017), ql.Date(9,2,2018),
         ql.Date(9,2,2019),ql.Date(9,2,2020), ql.Date(9,2,2022),
         ql.Date(9,2,2024), ql.Date(9,2,2027),ql.Date(9,2,2037),
         ql.Date(9,2,2047)]

rates = np.array([0.51 , 0.51 , 0.525, 0.54 , 0.64 ,
                   0.8  , 1.2  , 1.46 , 1.88 , 2.2  ,
                   2.4  , 2.74 , 3.02 ])

day_count = ql.ActualActual()
calc_date = ql.Date(9,2,2017)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calc_date

issue_date = contract["IssueDate"]
maturity_date = contract["MaturityDate"]
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)

coupon = contract["RealValue"]
settlement_days = contract["SettlementDays"]

# Determine Schedule
schedule = ql.Schedule(issue_date,
                       maturity_date,
                       tenor,
                       calendar,
                       accrual_convention,
                       accrual_convention,
                       Rule,
                       endofMonth)

# Initiate Zero Curve
curve = ql.ZeroCurve(dates,
                     rates,
                     ql.ActualActual(),
                     calendar,
                     ql.Linear())
curve.enableExtrapolation()
ts_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(curve)

def get_call_schedule(df, period=ql.Period(ql.Annual)):
    dates = df["StrikeDate"]
    prices = df["StrikePrice"]
    callability_schedule = ql.CallabilitySchedule()
    null_calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
    call_date = df["StrikeDate"][0]
    for time in range(len(df["StrikeDate"])):
        callability_price  = ql.CallabilityPrice(prices[time],
                                                 ql.CallabilityPrice.Clean)
        callability_schedule.append(ql.Callability(callability_price, 
                                                   ql.Callability.Call,
                                                   dates[time]))
        call_date = null_calendar.advance(call_date, period)
    return callability_schedule


callability_schedule = get_call_schedule(contract)

bond = ql.CallableFixedRateBond(settlement_days,
                                face_amount,
                                schedule,
                                [coupon],
                                day_count,
                                ql.Following,
                                face_amount,
                                calc_date,
                                callability_schedule)



def value_bond(a, s, ts_handle, grid_points, bond):
    model = ql.HullWhite(ts_handle, a, s)
    engine = ql.TreeCallableFixedRateBondEngine(model, grid_points)
    bond.setPricingEngine(engine)
    return bond

bondprice = value_bond(a, sigma, ts_handle, grid_points, bond)
OAS = bondprice.OAS(mkt_price,
                    ts_handle,
                    day_count,
                    compounding,
                    frequency)
bond_yield = bondprice.bondYield(mkt_price,
                                 day_count,
                                 compounding,
                                 frequency)

print(OAS)
print(bond_yield)
```

This yields an OAS value of -6.69 and a bond yield (YTM) of 0.121 or 12.1%. Is there a large difference if one were to consider a European option on the strike dates vs an American option, where the strikes are payable on the coupon payment dates!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rates are off by a factor of 100.  A rate of 2% needs to be written as 0.02, not 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the prepay penalty (call strike) very high so that it is always uneconomic to call, then observe/confirm that your OAS is zero. That would at least validate some of your overall setup. if it passes that test then I would incrementally make one of them economic, and try pricing the European option separately (you could do closed-form with Jamshidian Engine on top of your HW process which is affine) then see if the decompounded value of the option on the dv01 of the bond is close enough to your OAS (assuming the latter is positive). Although if you have a negative OAS with an American set of call dates, it's unlikely that it will become positive with an European call schedule. But these tests may provide some insights.